# Recursion Getting count of numbers that reside in AVL Tree

Tags: java, recursion

```
  public int count(Vertex T, int start, int end, int count) {

      if (T == null) {
          return -1;
      }

      count(T.left,start,end,count);
      int test=T.key;
      if(test >=start && testKey<end){
          count++;
      }

      System.out.print(T.key+"#"+count+"# ");                  
      count(T.right,start,end,count);

      return count;
   }
```

I am trying to get a count of numbers in a self-written, balancing search tree that is greater than or equal to my Start number and less than my End number.

So far my balancing search tree is correct, the only issue I have now is to correctly return the count. I have checked with the code above that it is counting correctly for numbers that matches my range however the issue I am having now is that I am unable to return the count I needed as it will return to 0 because of the nature of the recursive function call.

It would be helpful if I could get suggestions to return the desired count.

Comment: Please do NOT use the same name for a method and for a parameter to that method (or any other variable).  This is going to get horribly confusing.

Answer (score 1):

The `count` method returns a value that you just ignore.

You try to pass the `count` as parameter, this does not work as Java uses call by value. You won't get back the result via the parameter.

Instead, you want it to add to count, and to remove the `count` parameter (make it a local variable instead). For example:

```
count += count(T.left,start,end);
```

In the case where the node is `null` you should return 0 instead of -1.

Also note, that you are doing more work than necessary to solve the problem. For example if you reach a node that is `< start` you don't need to count the left subtree, all nodes in it will be smaller than `start`. Similarly with the right subtree if a node is `>= end`

Comment: thanks i think i got it to work with your help. i understand it i am doing more work but there are three possible cases 1) all values falls on the left 2)all values falls on the right and 3) the root could be in the middle of the range i specified and thus it will be on both ends.